# How hot can the focal point of a convex lens get under the full sun?

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, temperature, material-science, solar-cells

I could not find accurate data online apart from CSP power generators that could focus sun rays to a single point and heat a liquid to 1000°C.

I imagine many factors can affect the temperature, such as the length and shape of the lens, material of lens. But in applied theory, how hot can the temperature get?

**Background**

I saw a YouTube documentary purporting the use of a hypothetical solar-powered convex lens used to melt granite and pour the liquid into moulds to create perfectly shaped granite blocks used in ancient Egyptian construction projects, such as the Giza Pyramids.

The author asserts that this is more possible in that age when the wheel & gear, iron tools, and power tools had yet to be invented, especially considering the Giza Pyramid which comprises 2.3 million blocks of granite weighing 20-50 tons each, placed with exceptional precision.

Given the amount of pseudoscience that surround such topics, I am wary of such theories.

Note: This question is about the physics of such a lens, not about history.

Comment: The Giza pyramid is made mostly of limestone, not granite. The stones are not perfectly shaped. The stones do not weigh 20-50 tons each (about a tenth of that). I feel like something needs a bare modicum of facts to qualify as pseudoscience. The youtube video you watched was just complete nonsense.

Comment: You cant melt granite, then pour it, and expect to have granite in the end. That doesn't make any sense. Granite contains coarse grains of three different minerals - quartz, feldspar, and mica. If you melted it, it wouldn't be granite anymore, and when it solidified, it wouldn't solidify as granite. also, cutting and smoothing rocks isn't that hard. Almost every world culture has done it. Why do we need a convoluted explanation for how they made square rocks?

Comment: Note how neither of you could address anything relevant to the question (about Optics) and went on the tangent I warned about (History).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The theoretical maximum is exactly the surface temperature of the Sun, by thermodynamic arguments that the 2nd Law cannot be violated. We will, of course, fail to reach this limit by far. Long before that, the focused rays would ionise the air around the focal point.

Try not to waste too much time on pseudoscience.

Comment: Well, I would not know if it is pseudoscience unless I was learned in this subject, hence the question. But thanks for the information!

Comment: There is no way to make good mirrors in the past! Just about any "journey to the ancient past" story would invoke the cliche about mirrors.

Comment: The documentary was about lenses, not mirrors. I have doubts about the existence of converging lenses until more recent times.

Comment: Lol. Transparent objects like clear glass is also an incredibly new thing. The reason why it was absent in the past is because they couldn't get things hot enough. If they could melt granite, they would not have had such a problem.

Comment: How new is new? Epic of Izdubar and Ishtar, c.2000BC, reads: The King then rises, takes the sacred glass, 
And holds it in the sun before the mass
Of waiting fuel on the altar piled.
The centring rays--the fuel glowing gild
With a round spot of fire and quickly. spring
Above the altar curling, while they sing!